# Django override base_site.html for a custom admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I've created a custom admin thusly:

```
class RJBAdmin(AdminSite):
    def has_permission(self, request):
        """ Removed check for is_staff. """
        return request.user.is_active
rjb_admin = RJBAdmin(name='useradmin')
```

useradmin is hooked into the site urls.py via

```
url(r'^rjb_admin', include(rjb_admin.urls)),
```

I would like this admin to use some custom admin templates while the default admin continues to use its own templates.

I've created a custom base_site.html template in templates/admin/base_site.html.  I'm able to modify it and see the results in both the default admin.  However, I also see these changes in useradmin!

I've created a useradmin base_site.html in /templates/admin/rjb/base_site.html.  rjb is the app name.  Changes to this latter base_site.html have no impact on the useradmin admin.

How do I get user admin to use its own templates?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options

Answer (score 0):

You can use change_form_template or change_list_template template as per your need.

```
Example : 
class xxxxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  change_form_template ='admin/cutomize_form.html'
```

Regards,
Ansh J